# Parse User Class permission WRITE

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I see that, unchecking the User Class permission WRITE to avoid users creation, also new anonymous user cant no more login.

Is there another way to exclusively grant to my app the permission to create new users?

**Tried this but doesnt work with User Class permission WRITE unchecked:**
I get

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: This user is not allowed to perform the create operation on _User.

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
      if (e != null) {
         Log.d(" ", "Anonymous login failed.");
      } else {
         Log.d(" ", "Anonymous user logged in.");
      }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You're talking about parse.com and expect us to know that just because you had it as a tag ? Explain your problem properly and provide some sample code.

Comment: Are you trying to block username and password-based sign up while allowing anonymous users to log in ??

Comment: I would like allow anonymous user can login to use the user record in ACL, without granting a public WRITE class permission to User Class. Is possible?

Comment: What is the reason for that ? A user creation by definition requires public write access on User class. Just bear in mind that no one is allowed to write over any other user's data. If you want to block public write access to User class, you are forced to move your user creation code completely to cloud

Comment: Yes, but with public write access on User Class the data are exposed to a malicious insertion of any lot of fake users, or not?

Comment: Unfortunately by default, User class is potentially vulnerable to fake insertions.